# Can't check for/download updates

Tags: updates, update-manager

I've noticed I can't check for new updates, neither via terminal nor update manager. For example, update manager throws error saying something like "failed to download repository information. check your internet connection". Details are the following:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/slicer/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/slicer/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I did a bit of googling, still couldn't find any solution :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added some PPA to your system's package management which isn't available anymore. Try [this](http://bigbrovar.aoizora.org/index.php/2010/01/10/how-to-safely-remove-ppa-repository-from-ubuntu/) to remove the PPA and the packages installed from it.

Comment: Ah, right. I found the list of repos under the update settings, removed the ones shown in the error, it seems to work OK now.